# loading of different pages inside jquery ui tabs is slow and sometimes crashing

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

My boss wanted different process (which were originally individual pages) to show up on tabs

anyway I'm using the jquery ui tabs

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

my code

jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
$("#tabs-1").load("transaction.php");
$("#tabs-2").load("book.php");
$("#tabs-3").load("schedule.php");
});
</script>
```

html

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Transaction</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Book</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Schedule</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
```

each page pulls up data in mysql database 
the problem is, book.php has lots of data so loading it is slow and sometimes the browser crashes

is this implementation possible or should I explain this that using tabs is not recommended, this should be showed using individual pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you could do is get the book.php to only load when tab 2 is clicked.

```
$("#tabs-2").click(function(){
    $("#tabs-2").load("book.php");
});
```

this should help to stop it crashing straight away. 
if it doesn't help you will need to optimise you query.

you could also try using ajax.

put this in you document load and hopefully it should load the contents of book.php into the tab.

```
  $.get( "book.php", function(book) {
    $("#tabs-2").html(book);
  });
```

Jquery Sample

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "page_url",
   data: $("#advserc").serialize() + "&pagenum=" + page, // i sent the page through with it
  beforeSend:function(){  // this unhides a div with gif loading image in it.
        //show gif here, eg:
        $("#loading").show();

    },
    complete:function(){
        //hide gif here, eg:
        $("#loading").hide(); // this hides the div
    },
   success: function(data){
      $("#content-container").html(data); // here i fill the div with the dat from the php page
   }
});
```

Comment: for unknown reason, it doesnt load,i tried putting it also inside of <div id="tabs-2"></div> but it doesnt load too

Comment: make sure that the code above is out side of the document load function.

Comment: i tried <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#tabs-2").click(function(){
    $("#tabs-2").load("book.php");
});
</script> but it still the same

Comment: it works thank you but, a while ago my boss added records equalling to 1800+ records and its slow, i think I'll revert back to the individual page

Comment: Are you doing a simple SELECT * on you book.php or is it a complex query?

Comment: anyway the page isnt just pulling data, but it has search, pagination and other stuff plus the volume of data maybe that's why

Comment: Most likely, if you want to keep it in a tab you will need to use jquery's ajax function. also serialize is useful when using ajax

Comment: Oh I see, May I know more about serialize?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ this is the link on jquery's website about serialize. i will add a sample of my code above

Comment: thanks for the sample code, I noticed the gif described is preloaded, do you think hiding and showing pages will run smooth?

Comment: I would think so, but i would test and see how it goes.

Comment: ok let's see how it goes, have a page pull 1800+ records if possible